# Uncaught ReferenceError: selectAll is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to clear my appended table to prevent element duplication, using for loop. But in the chrome console, below error occurred.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: selectAll is not defined.
```

Here is my code snippet.

```
var userlistings = selectAll('userlisting')

    for(var i = 0; i < userlistings.length; i++){

    userlistings[i].remove();

    }
```

Could anyone please help me with this error?

Comment: The error is clear... There's no variable/function with name `selectAll`

Comment: The name of the function is `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Also, the selector should probably have a `.` at the beginning, to indicate that it's a class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling a function called selectAll which isnt defined in your code, thats why youre getting a message saying it's undefined

You should call the browser dom method document.querySelectorAll

```
var userlistings = document.querySelectorAll('userlisting')
```